# Webhook for Facebook Group Comment

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-webhooks

How can I get comments from a **Group** using Facebook Webhook? I want to get the comments from a group instantly using webhook. My app is verified with *publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info* permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The object types you can subscribe to for getting updates, are listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference

As you can see, `Group` is not mentioned there. You can not currently subscribe for webhook updates from Groups.

| Topic | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Ad Account | List of Ad account fields you can subscribe to. |
| Application | Category of updates that are sent to a specific app |
| Certificate Transparency | Category of updates related to Certificate Transparency |
| Instagram | Category of updates relating to activity on Instagram user |
| Page | Full list of page profile fields you can subscribe to. Fields of this topic require at least one page admin to grant the 'manage_pages' permission to your app. The page admin also needs to have at least moderator privileges in order to receive all content. |
| Permissions | Category of updates relating to a user's granting or revoking a permission to your app |
| User | Full list of user profile fields that you can subscribe to. |
| Whatsapp Business Account | Category of updates relating to a WhatsApp business account. |

Comment: Depending on how many groups you are monitoring, you can poll once per minute and stay under the API limit pretty easily. I poll my feed every minute for 16 hours per day and the Facebook status page shows me at about 25% utilization.

If you're getting the comments as well, that will increase your API usage because you'll have to do a "feed" query every minute and then a "comments" query for every new post.